# Everything is in the Torah

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study

Someone mentioned that there is a statement of our Rabbis, "There is nothing on earth that is not hinted at in the Torah."*

Does anyone know where such a statement can be found?

Comment: יתיב ר' יוחנן וקא מתמה אמר מי איכא מידי דכתיבי בכתובי דלא רמיזי באורייתא

Comment: @GershonGold ...which means that everything mentioned in Tanach is hinted to in the Chumash.

Comment: How do you know it says that?

Comment: Who claims it says that?  Where did you see this?

Comment: Look in Avos 5:26.

Comment: Gershon, what is your Mekor?

Comment: @user8553 *Ta'anis* 9a, as indicated in an earlier version of the question.

Comment: The question is clear

Comment: Im with @Laser123. Why was this closed?

Comment: I don't know where, but I am aware of this statement. It is obviously not a literal statement. foe example, the Torah never mentions oranges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One source for this is the introduction of the Ramban to Sefer Bereishis, where he says that the 50 gates of wisdom minus one that were given to Moshe represent knowledge about all that is in creation, and this was all given to Moshe, either explictly or hinted to in a letter, the forms of the letters, changes in the forms of the letters, Gematrios, etc. in the Torah.

This is also the commonly understood meaning of what the Zohar (2:161a) says "אסתכל בה באורייתא וברא עלמא" - G-d looked in the Torah and created the world, that for anything to exist it has to exist in the Torah first, and thus the Torah determines what it is.

Answer (score 4):

another source. Vilna Gaon commentary on sefer detzinuata 55a

> "all that ever was, is and will be is in the torah. And not just the
>   general things but rather even every detail of each specific person,
>   everything that happened to him from his birth till his end, and all
>   of his gilgulim, and all the details and the details of his details,
>   and likewise for every animal, every plant, every inanimate object and
>   all its details and details of details..."

I once heard from a kabalist that the term "torah" is from the word "Tor" which means "the turn", i.e. like when someone stands in line waiting his turn. It sets the "turn" of every event from creation till eternity.

Answer (score 3):

Pirqe'i Avot 5:22 [states](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%91) (my translation):

> בן בג בג אומר, הפך בה והפך בה, דכלא בה.
>
> Ben Bag Bag says, 'Delve in her and delve in her, for all is within her'.

Rabbe'inu 'Ovadyah MiBartenura explains:

> הפוך בה והפוך בה - בתורה
>
> *Delve in **her** and delve in **her*** - In the Torah

Answer (score 3):

[R. Eleazar Rokeah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_of_Worms) writes in Sefer HaShem (p. 43) that everything is hinted to in the Torah:

> ללמדך כי כל דבר רמוז בתורה אלא שנעלם מבני אדם
>
> To teach you that everything is hinted to in the Torah, but it is hidden form people.

A similar sweeping statement is made by R. Nattan of Clermont (late 13th century) in his commentary to the haggada (published in Moriah 257-9 (5759)):

> שכל הענינים רמוזים בתורה
>
> All things are hinted to in the Torah.

Comment: Note also Rabbenu Bahya's comment that all wisdom is hidden in the Torah: ספר כד הקמח סוכה 
וכן שאר כל החכמות בלי ספק כלן רמוזות בתורה, ולכך נקראת תמימה שנא' (תהלים יט) תורת ה' תמימה ואלו היתה חסרת חכמה אחת מכל החכמות לא היה קורא אותה תמימה

Answer (score 1):

Zohar ([3:221a](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.3.221a.4?vhe=New_Torat_Emet_Zohar&lang=bi))

דלית לך מלה זעירא דלא תשכח לה באורייתא